# DBAN under PC for an HDD using MAC OSx

Tags: data-recovery

A HDD with OSx installed removed from mac and used DBAN to wipe it under a PC. Does all the data is lost even if we put it back on a mac machine ?

Answer (score 2):

## Yes.

It doesn't matter whether the host is a Mac or a PC. DBAN is it's own operating system, and works the same, regardless of hardware. DBAN overwrites the entire hard disk multiple times with zeroes and garbage data.

Recovery is impossible if the process was completed.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification.